# Mini Cart issue in XML

Tags: layout, xml, topmenu

For some reason the mini cart disappear from my website. I don't know why? and how do I debug it ?

this is the code from my layout:

```
<remove name="topMenu"/>
            <block type="experius_linkmanager/link_list" name="linkmanager.topnav" as="topMenu">
                <action method="setIdentifier"><key>hoesjes-topmenu</key></action>
                <action method="insert"><blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName></action>
            </block>
```

and this is from the header.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

Any idea how do I debug this ? What should be the reason of disappearance ? 
**[UPDATE]**
This is the structure of my theme:

```
frontend/mytheme/base/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml
frontend/mytheme/default/template/ no checkout
frontend/mytheme/othername/template/checkout/ no cart folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously that is the reason:

```
<remove name="topMenu"/>
```

Comment: So what about that? I removed it , but it still doesn't appear

Comment: @AttilaNaghi did you clear the cache after?

Comment: yeah sure, I put all of the xml backup. but it still the same, It is not an xml problem. Any other idea ?

Comment: look how block with name topMenu is defined in your layout

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<remove name="topMenu"/>` 
and also check your `local.xml` in that template if present.

Comment: it is not , any other idea ?